# Square in a finite field

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, finite-fields, legendre-symbol

I need to prove: $a$ is a square in $\mathbb{Z}$ iff $a\mod p$ is a square in $\mathbb{F_p}$ for every $p$ prime. First side ($\rightarrow$) is trivial and is derived directly from multiplicativity of modulo. Now I need to prove the other side ($\leftarrow$). I tried taking $p>a$ so $a\equiv a\mod p$, and I know that $a$ is a square so there exists $b<p$ s.t $\space$$b^2\mod p \equiv a$. But, $b$ is not necessarily the root of $a$ in $\mathbb{Z}$, so I'm stuck. I also know that for each $p$, $(\frac{a}{p})=1$ but this doesn't get me anywhere. Any hint would help.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki fixed it for every $p$ prime, thanks

Comment: $b$ is not necessarily the root of $a$ in $\mathbb{Z}$ ? Why

Comment: Not that it seems to help an awful lot, but we do have http://oeis.org/A144294. There might be better and more accessible primes to go for than "the lowest", though.

Comment: if $a\ne0$, there actually exist two $b<p$ s.t. $b^2\equiv a\pmod p$, because if $b$ satisfies that, then so does $p-b$

Comment: @M.Di The argument is a little awkwardly written there but consider e.g. $a=10$, $p=13$. $a$ is a square in $\mathbb{F}_p$, and $a\lt p$ but $a$ isn't a square in $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki:  I think OP is saying $a$ is a square in $\mathbb F_p$ for all $p$, not just $13$

Comment: @StevenStadnicki But also $10$ _isn't_ a square modulo $7$. Which is the point of this problem: show that there always is at least one prime that makes $a$ non-square modulo that prime, as long as $a$ itself is non-square.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner I understand that; I was just saying what '$b$ is not necessarily the root of $a$ in $\mathbb{Z}$' means, as I understand it, trying to clarify that point.

Comment: Working with just a 'sufficiently large' $p$ won't be enough to show what you're after; for instance, 2 is not a square in $\mathbb{Z}$ but it _is_ a square modulo infinitely many primes (by reciprocity). So the argument is going to have to be more thorough than just that.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki I'll clarify what I mean. If for every $p$ prime, $a \mod p $ is a square in $\mathbb{F_p}$, then it is a square in $\mathbb{Z}$. It has to be a square in every finite field for the argument to work, obviously, but I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: Cf. [this unanswered question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2816644/a-square-modulo-every-prime-is-a-square-proof-valid) and [this answered question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6976/an-integer-is-a-nth-power-if-that-holds-true-for-all-moduli)

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Just for my own understanding, is 27 a square in $\mathbb{F_3}$?

Comment: @user2661923:  I would say yes, because $27\equiv 0^2\bmod \mathbb F_3$

Comment: Note that $7$ is a square  modulo $19, 29, 31, 37, 47, 53, $ and $59$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner I was afraid that you were going to say that.  If that were not the case, then the $\leftarrow$ proof becomes trivial, since $a$ is a square $\iff$ all of the exponents in its prime factorization are even.  Oh well.

Answer (score 0):

If think the easiest way is to use quadratic reciprocity, that if $a$ is not a square then for $p\ne 2$,
$(\frac{a}p) =\chi(p) $ with $\chi$ a non-trivial Dirichlet character modulo $4a$,

there is $m>0$ such that $\chi(m)=-1$, some prime $p|m$ is such that $-1=\chi(p)=(\frac{a}p)$

Comment: While I am familiar with QR, I'm not familiar with Dirichlet characters. Is there another way to approach the contra-positive?

Comment: $n\to (\frac{n}q)$ is the quadratic Dirichlet character modulo $q$ (completely multiplicative and $q$ periodic); quadratic reciprocity is saying that $\chi$ is completely multiplicative and periodic and not always $1$ or $0$. Completely multiplicative implies that if all the $p|m$ are such that $\chi(p)=1$ then $\chi(m)=1$.